# Why does RStudio opens a former versions of an R script when I open it using a VPN?

Tags: r, file, rstudio

I noticed that sometimes, RStudio opens a versions of my R scripts that are not the latest saved.

The script appears with a red name, suggesting it was not saved.

[image]

It happens when I use a VPN on my company's laptop.

To fix this problem, I close RStudio and reopen it. Then sometimes, the script appears as it was last saved.

Any reason or fix to this issue?